# The community generated "Duplicate Answers" flag should be auto-dismissed if the user deletes their answer

Tags: feature-request, flags, duplicate-answers, self-delete, moderator-queue

If a user duplicates their answer in another post, we get an automatically generated flag in the queue that states "duplicate answers - `<link to answer>`".  Sometimes when this happens, the user already deleted their duplicate post, causing the flag to be irrelevant.

Feature request: If a user deletes a post flagged as a 'duplicate answer' by the community user, the user deleting that post should dismiss the flag.

Comment: I dunno. If a user has a habit of bumping questions with the same answer we should look into it regardless.

Comment: That's certainly a possibility, but I've never seen that happen (I'm not claiming it doesn't happen).  What I have seen when a user deletes their own duplicated post is 1) a user posts an answer duplicating an earlier answer, but doesn't realize he posted it to the wrong question, and deletes it. 2) Posts a duplicate answer, and then edits it (after the process to detect duplicates as run), causing the answer to no longer be a duplicate.

Comment: Is it wrong to use the same boilerplate answer twice and adjust it a little bit?

Comment: @Undo So long as you tailor the answer to the question asked, you can have whatever you want in the body. If you're posting the same answer to multiple questions, that's usually a sign that the questions are either 1) highly related or 2) duplicates.  If the latter, we ask the duplicate question be closed. If the former, then the answer should be tailored specifically.